# How to ALWAYS show scrollbar in iframe in HTML5

Tags: css, html, iframe, scroll

Is there a way to always show a scrollbar on an iframe in HTML5, even if the content is not overflowing? The `scrolling="yes`" attribute doesn't work in HTML5. Is there a way using CSS?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think setting the css `overflow` property to `scroll` will do it

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but setting overflow to scroll on the iframe tag doesn't work. Like the replier below has suggested, setting body { overflow: scroll } on the embedded document makes it work.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right, well I was in the right direction then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `scrolling="yes"` was supported by some early browsers only. Judging from simulation of older versions in IE 11, it seems that IE 8 dropped the support: although the attribute as such is recognized, the value `yes` is not—scroll bars are shown only when the content does not fit in.

This is a change in browser practices. It has nothing to do with HTML5. In fact, HTML5 [describes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#frames-and-framesets) the attribute `scrolling="yes"` as mapping to the CSS setting `overflow: scroll`, which is somewhat misleading.

Modern browsers implement `iframe` so that the scroll bars are present, if needed for accessing all of the content, but not otherwise. Using `scrolling=no` or `overflow: hidden`, you can prevent the scroll bars from appearing, but not make them appear if the content fits (there is no overflow).

To make scroll bars appear, you need to make the *embedded* document set them up, e.g. by using `body { overflow: scroll }` in it. Then it does not matter what the `iframe` element says. The scroll bars will be passive (and light grey), when the content actually fits, but they will be there are occupy space, and they turn to active scroll bars as the content expands so that it does not fit. In the following example, I am embedding a page that sets `body { overflow: scroll }` and has an editable `body` element, so that you can add lines and see how the bars change:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/hello.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an add on, if you only want to have scrollbars showing in one direction and not both you can use the specific y and x css.

I wanted a vertical scrollbar showing all the time for the look of it but not the horizontal as width never changed.

So I used:

{overflow-y: scroll;}

The other one (in this case overflow-x) will default to auto and only show if needed.